# Adding href and id property leads to framing error

Tags: javascript, dom, href

After fetching a list of images, I want to show them on a grid; it works after patching frames, but it keeps spiting out the following error: `TypeError: win[(("HTML" + (intermediate value)) + "Element")] is undefined`

Relevant code:

```js
const grid = document.querySelector('#img-grid')
var results = [
    {score: 7, favs: 4, id: 1234, preview: 'example.com/image.png'}
    // etc...
]
function showPosts() {
    grid.replaceChildren()
    results.map((post, i) => {
        const article = document.createElement('article')
        const a       = document.createElement('a')
        const div     = document.createElement('div')
        const img     = document.createElement('img')
        
        article.classList.add(['img-res'])
        // `viewing-page` is just a div that holds a bigger image
        a.href = '#viewing-page' //! This line leads to the error
        a.onclick = view
        a.id = i
        img.src = post['preview']
        div.innerText = getSortVal(post) // `getSortVal` return either `.score`, `.favs`, or `.id`, based on a `select` sorting option
        
        a.appendChild(img)
        article.appendChild(a)
        article.appendChild(div)
        grid.appendChild(article) // Traceback points to this line on my code
    })
}
```

The `href` is just for the page to scroll down from the gallery to the viewing page.

On a NoScript library, it tries to access a `HTMLFrameElement` property from the `a` anchor:

```js
// NoScript Commons Library (patchWindow.js)
function modifyFramingElements(win) { // win is the `a` element when the error occurs
    for (let property of ["contentWindow", "contentDocument"]) {
      for (let iface of ["Frame", "IFrame", "Object"]) {
        let proto = win[`HTML${iface}Element`].prototype; // throws here
        modifyContentProperties(proto, property)
      }
    }
    // ...
```

I've discovered that the `win` argument will be whatever was assigned the `id` `i`. So if I do `img.id = i` instead, then `win` will be the `img` element.

The `HTMLFrameElement` interface is deprecated, so I don't even know why it's still trying to access it.

After removing the `href` assignment, it stops giving errors, which is very strange, as it's just a way to scroll down to the viewing page area.

Changing the appending order didn't stop the error.

Here's the whole error message:

```
TypeError: win[(("HTML" + (intermediate value)) + "Element")] is undefined
    modifyFramingElements moz-extension://d5a0cd25-8ab0-4971-bfe9-992ee8de967f/nscl/content/patchWindow.js:291
    modifyWindow moz-extension://d5a0cd25-8ab0-4971-bfe9-992ee8de967f/nscl/content/patchWindow.js:268
    patchAll moz-extension://d5a0cd25-8ab0-4971-bfe9-992ee8de967f/nscl/content/patchWindow.js:304
    apply moz-extension://d5a0cd25-8ab0-4971-bfe9-992ee8de967f/nscl/content/patchWindow.js:321
    showPosts http://localhost:8080/script.js:65
    showPosts http://localhost:8080/script.js:49
    search http://localhost:8080/script.js:30
    onclick http://localhost:8080/#viewing-page:1
 Patching frames[0] patchWindow.js:306:19
    patchAll moz-extension://d5a0cd25-8ab0-4971-bfe9-992ee8de967f/nscl/content/patchWindow.js:306
    apply moz-extension://d5a0cd25-8ab0-4971-bfe9-992ee8de967f/nscl/content/patchWindow.js:321
    showPosts http://localhost:8080/script.js:65
    showPosts http://localhost:8080/script.js:49
    search http://localhost:8080/script.js:30
```

Comment: Any time `win[`HTML${iface}Element`]` is `null` or `undefined`, you'll get an exception. You can simply test that value to ensure that it's non-null before trying to access the `.prototype` property.

Comment: @Pointy The second code block is not mine, it's the browser's; I cannot edit it. I've added the source as a comment for clarity.

Comment: Looks like it's part of the library that the comment says it's part of. But wherever it comes from, that loop will definitely cause exceptions to be thrown.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with your problem, but `article.classList.add(['img-res'])` is constructed incorrectly. It should be `article.classList.add('img-res')`, or I suppose `article.classList.add(...['img-res'])` if you actually have an array you want to spread to arguments.

Comment: This seems like a bug in the library. Are you sure you have the latest version?

Comment: `win` shouldn't be the anchor element, I think it's supposed to be `window`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Both work; I did it that way because it is defined as `(method) DOMTokenList.add(...tokens: string[]): void`

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I use Firefox, and it's at 123.0. I did some more tests, and it seems that the error is triggered by adding the `href`, but `win` is whatever is assigned the `id` `i`, so if I instead do `img.id = i`, then `win` will be the `img` element.
I'll add this clue to the main post.

Comment: How is `modifyFramingElement` being called?

Comment: It works because `['img-res'].toString()` === `'img-res'` if you had more than one element in your array, it would fail. `add(...tokens: string[])` means you can do `add(token0)`, `add(token0, token1)`, `add(token0, token1, ..., tokenN)`.

Comment: @Barmar `apply`->`patchAll`->`modifyWindow`->`modifyFramingElements`

All of them inside `patchWindow.js`

I've added the whole call stack at the end in any case.

Comment: I still don't understand how it's getting into `patchWindow.js`. Does this extension modify how assigning to `href` works? I think you need to report this to the extension author.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the NoScript extension is still using the aforementioned `HTMLFrameElement` interface, which is deprecated, causing it to throw when it cannot read its attributes.

It's still weird as I have localhost as trusted, and NoScript disabled (not as an extension, though).

I opened an issue on their repository.